# How to import a selector style into another selector style?

Tags: css, tags

I know that we can import a css style into another css style. That's not the thing I'm going to talk about.

I want to create a css style that depend on other css style. In other word, I want to create my own cascading tree system. How can I do that?

For example, how I pictured it in my mind:

```
div.priceinfo    { border: 1px solid gray; width: 200px; }
div.disabled     { background-color: gray; color: 333333; }
div.shippinginfo { depend: div.pricebox; border-color: green; }
div.taxinfo      { depend: div.pricebox; border-color: blue; }
```

so I can use it like this:

```
<div class="priceinfo"> ... </div>
<div class="shippinginfo"> ... </div>
<div class="taxinfo disabled"> ... </div>
```

but I do **not** want like this:

```
<div class="priceinfo shippinginfo"> ... </div>
<div class="priceinfo taxinfo disabled"> ... </div>
```

I know that the last way is possible, but I'm curious whether there's any way I can do something like the one I described earlier? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to see a `LESS CSS` for this. a `LESS CSS` provides a coding for `CSS`.
http://lesscss.org

Comment: well, it still not exactly what I'm looking for, but I think it's a start. Thanks. :)